# Replacing blank with "NA" or "MISSING" text

Tags: mdx, slimdx, mdxstudio

I am trying to replace *blank* spaces in data with the "MISSING" or "NA" text.

```
CoalesceEmpty([Product Type].[All Product Type].[                  ],"MISSING")
```

I have tried the above code, with or without quotes around MISSING.

Getting the following error:
**CoalesceEmpty([Product Type].[All Product Type].[                  ],"MISSING") is invalid and cannot be used in a query.**

P.S. Product Type is a dimension.

I tried this function on `measures` and it worked fine there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what this gap means - do you really have a member that is called `[     ]`?! ... `[Product Type].[All Product Type].[                  ]`

We also need to see the whole script - the context for this snippet - to accurately help you.

If you wanted to test the `currentmember` of the hierarchy `[Product Type].[All Product Type]` for null then you could do the following:

```
IIF(
  [Product Type].[All Product Type].currentmember.membervalue = 0,
  "MISSING",
  [Product Type].[All Product Type].currentmember.membervalue
)
```

In the cubes I play with the above would never happen as all members exist so all members have a `membervalue`. Here is an example of replacing blanks:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount 2] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] = 0
     ,'MISSING'
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount 2]
  } ON 0
 ,
    [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].MEMBERS
  * 
    [Product].[Category].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

The new measure I've created results in the 4 column below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**CoalesceEmpty** function doesn't accept members or sets. Both the parameters need to be numeric expressions. See the msdn link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146080.aspx)

Comment: It does accept , strings right? as i can see
String syntax
CoalesceEmpty(String_Expression1 [ ,String_Expression2,...n] )

Comment: Yes it does but your first parameter ain't a string mate! It's a member.